# msys path error due to space in the directory name

Tags: windows, mingw, msys

I launched the msys console and checked the path environment variable. I got the following:

```
$ $PATH
sh: /c/Users/wud/AppData/Local/Continuum/Miniconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/:.:/us
r/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Obviously the space in "Program Files" is the culprit. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem there is that you just did `$PATH` and not `echo $PATH`. By doing that, you tried to run your path as if it were a program, rather than just display it. There's no actual problem with a space in your path.